# Multi-boot Windows 7, Windows XP and Windows 8 Release Preview

Tags: windows, multi-boot, windows-8-preview, boot-manager

I want to test the Windows 8 Release Preview, but I am not sure how my boot configuration will turn out.

Currently, I dual boot Windows XP with Windows 7, using the Windows 7 boot manager. If I add a new partition and install Windows 8, will my boot configuration stay intact with Windows 8 added as a new option or will I have to update it manually so I get a triple boot menu?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 installation will update your boot configuration data(BCD) to boot all installed Windows versions. 
To view and edit complete contents of BCD you can use [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net). The tool has also the unique capability to add automatically (on click) installed Windows versions if not present in BCD store.

Answer (score 1):

You might find yourself in trouble trying to use the Windows default bootloader. As an alternative, I would recommend using [EasyBCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyBCD). It's free to install and should allow you to easily configure multiple operating systems.